# Why Java.io.File has a restriction to delete a non-empty directory?

Tags: java, python, jvm

According to this `Java` [Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#delete%28%29) `java.io.File` `delete()` method has a restriction to delete non-empty directory. (But there is a bunch of workarounds for that).

On the other hand `Python` runs in its own virtual machine (analogue of `JVM`) called `Interpreter`. And it has a method to delete such directories

By the way, it's possible to create infinitely recursive directory structures (in both [Windows](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/12/27/332704.aspx) and Linux (with symbolic links)), what will cause a loop. But, I guess, it's not the main reason, why there is an exception.

So, why `java.io.File` has a restriction to delete a non-empty directory?

**Edit**: why there is no layer between low level system call like "rm -rf" and `Java` code?

**Edit:** the question is NOT **how**, but **why**

Comment: I believe its just to make sure that you don't delete a non-empty directory (and files inside it) by mistake.. Just a guess..

Comment: But, you can make the same mistake in case of using handwritten recursive algorithm. I hope there is a more justifiable reason)))

Comment: Well.. Atleast you will be knowing that you are recusively trying to delete the files and something might go horribly wrong... Its like Linux OS, you need to be a super user to do rm -r *

Comment: Most operating systems provide a `RemoveDirectory` call that will only function in the case of the directory being empty. This is most likely a formalism of this condition.

Comment: @TheLostMind: that's not the same. Both `Java` and `Python` run in a sandbox, so you can't translate `Shell` commands to the hosting OS

Comment: @Ivan: I think its not about translating, but giving analogy. like in shell by default rm will not delete non empty directories unless you explicitly provide 'rm -r'. this gives you second chance to recover from silly things like 'rm /' (might be blocked on that OS too) or 'rm *' from '/'  in case you have the write permissions. Its more about design/intentions than capabilities. (you can always write an API to recursively delete the files, but that again means its intentional)

Answer (score 0):

It mirrors the behaviour of underlying C library system calls. `rmdir` function also deletes only empty directories.

Answer (score 0):

Both on Linux and Windows commands that remove file/directory do not do this operation for subdirectories unless this was explicitly requested. For example on Linux you have to use `rm -r` to remove directories tree.

Java does not re-invent the world. JDK uses low-level system calls that do not remove directory tree. You can however use 3rd party pure java utilities that do it.

BTW you cannot really create infinite directory structure. It is an illusion. Symbolic links are just special files that are recognized by shell commands. It is not a problem to remove symbolic links as a regular files and do not follow them even if them refer to directory.

Comment: Yes, I agree that there is a system level tools to perform such operations (Windows, Unix, etc.). But why there is no layer between `Java` code and these tools call? Is the security a main reason? But why `Python` has such method?

Comment: These questions should be sent to Java and Python creators. Generally JDK does not implement all you can imagine. It leaves some work to other software engineers. Python creator decided to implement such method. Well done!

Comment: I understand that on some answers can give only `Java` designers themselves. But a "layer" I mentioned above is so obvious. That's why I want to find enought justifiable reason

Comment: No reasons. Just design decision. And concept: leave some work to other developers.